# Vagrant network configuration not working for Ubuntu VM within Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 8.1 machine. I have installed Vagrant and VirtualBox. If I start an Ubuntu VM (ubuntu/trusty32) up using VirtualBox it seems to start fine. I can then use the following command to connect:

```
> vagrant ssh
```

However, if I instead use Vagrant to start the VM so that it can set it all up correctly for a Ruby on Rails environment, it times out. The command I use is:

```
> vagrant up
```

When this times out, I use VirtualBox to connect to the VM, and I see the following issues:

```
waiting for network device
gave up waiting for network device
route info failed

waiting for network configuration
booting system without full Network Configuration
```

This to me, looks like a problem with my Vagrant configuration setup for the network. I got my Vagrant config from [gorails.com](https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development) which had this as the network setup:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

This looks like it is forwarding the Ruby port (3000) to the VM machine. This does not appear to set up my network correctly. I have also tried variations like:

```
config.vm.network :private_network,ip: "192.168.2.100"
config.vm.network :private_network,ip: "10.1.2.100"
```

I have the following network config on my machine:

```
Ethernet - using 10.1.2.91 (static)
WiFi     - disabled
```

Any ideas? Network issues are not my strong point.

### UPDATE

The network set up seems identical when I run showvminfo from VBoxManage. However, if I log into the Ubuntu VM, and run "ifconfig -a" the VM that is started with Vagrant is missing the following line:

```
inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem. It was Hyper-V causing issues. Running this command in an elevated command prompt did the trick.

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix using the [following workaround](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/391#issuecomment-2078383)

> 1. login with :gui by login/pass: vagrant/vagrant
> 2. modify the `/etc/rc.local` file  to include the line `sh /etc/init.d/networking restart` just before `exit 0`.
> 3. disable :gui
> 4. vagrant reload

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this did not make any difference.